Why does my router always malfunction even when swapped out by the ISP?
I've been experiencing consistent huge spikes recently, so to troubleshoot a bit, I try to ping my router:
C:\Users\****>ping 10.0.0.1
Pinging 10.0.0.1 with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from 10.0.0.1: bytes=32 time=3742ms TTL=64
Request timed out.
Reply from 10.0.0.1: bytes=32 time=4ms TTL=64
Reply from 10.0.0.1: bytes=32 time=2ms TTL=64
Ping statistics for 10.0.0.1:
    Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 3, Lost = 1 (25% loss),
Approximate round trip times in milli-seconds:
    Minimum = 2ms, Maximum = 3742ms, Average = 1249ms.

So the conclusion is that the router is at fault. I call my ISP techs, they swap the router. It works for a day or so, then the exact same issue repeats itself.
For context, this is a shared house I live in with other residents.
What's going on?

You replace hardware the problem continues so it’s either the Ethernet cable or the hardware you haven’t replaced

@Ramhound wouldn't the issue not be fixed for any amount of time after the replacement then? Why would it work for 1 day?
Also, I am using the PCI internet adapter, but it's definitely not an issue with my PC since other devices experience the same lag

was the replacement router identical to the old one? ISP provided routers are not known for their quality.

@JaromandaX yep

It is far more likely that one of the housemates uses an insane amount of traffic that the router is struggling to cope with, like downloading torrents. If the router is busy handling requests, ping times will be high. Connect only your pc to the router when the problem happens again, and see if it goes away. If so, connect one cable back again, and test again, and do that until all cables are connected again. If the router also does wifi, consider changing the password so you can test. Its more likely a clogged connection than broken hardware.

You ask "why would it work one day ?". Thats likely because by swapping out the router, the connection to the offending device was temporarely severed. Since you live in shared accomodation, i would talk to the other residents and ask if they have similar problems or if they make excessive use of the network causing issues for others.

@Silbee the issue was fixed for 3 weeks after the router replacement, and just came back again. 2 Questions to your point:

Would excessive network use ever cause packet loss?
If there was an offending device, wouldn't the issues come up way sooner than 3 weeks? Why would it start spiking 3 weeks in and not 1-2 days in?


@fane-eternal 1) Yes, excessive network usage can lead to packet loss. Especially on equipment not made to handle it correctly. 2) Faulty hardware can get very funky. I've had network equipment exhibit faults only in very specific circumstances. While unlikely and not super common, it can (and does) happen.  I think the takeaway from all this is what Ramhound and LPChip already mentioned too. If the router has been replaced, wouldnt it make most sense its another device in the network causing issues ? Wouldnt hurt to ask the other residents if they have similar issues ?
